# Unable to get my Loop to Update lines with rows

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

trying to learn loops and wanted to output all the rows from this query but the counter works and the variables have no data stored.

I've declared everything and what i think has been assigned to the columns but just not getting the output i need

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE 1000000;
DECLARE 
    n_counter NUMBER := 0;
    v_site is_spool_dir.site%TYPE;
    v_client is_spool_dir.client%TYPE;
    v_name IS_PRINTS_NAME.name_comment%TYPE;
    v_id is_spool_dir.identification%TYPE;
    v_date is_spool_dir.last_print%TYPE;
BEGIN
    FOR item IN (
        SELECT
            s.site
            ,s.client
            ,p.name_comment
            ,s.identification
            ,to_char(s.last_print, 'DD/MM/RRRR HH24:MM:SS') INTO v_site, v_client, v_name, v_id, v_date
        FROM
            is_spool_dir s
            ,is_prints_name p
        WHERE
           to_char(s.last_print, 'DD/MM/YYYY') like '18/01/2019'
           and s.site = '7'
           and s.client = 'BREV'
           and s.identification like 'BREZ%'
           and p.id = s.report_id
        ORDER BY
           to_char(s.last_print, 'DD/MM/YYYY'))
    LOOP 
    n_counter := n_counter + 1;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(n_counter);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_site ||','|| v_client ||','|| v_name ||','|| v_id ||','|| v_date);
    IF n_counter = 1000 THEN
      EXIT;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

OUTPUT

```
1
,,,,
2
,,,,
3
,,,,
4
,,,,
5
,,,,
6
,,,,
7
,,,,
8
,,,,
9
,,,,
10
,,,,
11
,,,,
12
,,,,
13
,,,,
14
,,,,
15
,,,,
16
,,,,
17
,,,,
18
,,,,
19
,,,,
20
,,,,
21
,,,,
22
,,,,
23
,,,,
24
,,,,
25
,,,,
26
,,,,
27
,,,,
28
,,,,
29
,,,,
30 etc
```

Answer (score 3):

When you declare a cursor for your loop you do not use an into clause.

If you really want to put them into variables you can do an assignment in your loop like this...

```
v_site := item.site;
```

Otherwise just use the item variable you have declared in your loop as below

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE 1000000;
DECLARE 
    n_counter NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
    FOR item IN (
        SELECT
            s.site
            ,s.client
            ,p.name_comment
            ,s.identification
            ,to_char(s.last_print, 'DD/MM/RRRR HH24:MM:SS')
        FROM
            is_spool_dir s
            ,is_prints_name p
        WHERE
           to_char(s.last_print, 'DD/MM/YYYY') like '18/01/2019'
           and s.site = '7'
           and s.client = 'BREV'
           and s.identification like 'BREZ%'
           and p.id = s.report_id
        ORDER BY
           to_char(s.last_print, 'DD/MM/YYYY'))
    LOOP 
    n_counter := n_counter + 1;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(n_counter);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(item.v_site ||','|| item.v_client ||','|| item.v_name ||','|| item.v_id ||','|| item.v_date);
    IF n_counter = 1000 THEN
      EXIT;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use  cursor with pollowing way :

```
FOR CUR IN (  SELECT
        s.site
        ,s.client
        ,p.name_comment
        ,s.identification
        ,to_char(s.last_print, 'DD/MM/RRRR HH24:MM:SS')
    FROM
        is_spool_dir s
        ,is_prints_name p
    WHERE
       to_char(s.last_print, 'DD/MM/YYYY') like '18/01/2019'
       and s.site = '7'
       and s.client = 'BREV'
       and s.identification like 'BREZ%'
       and p.id = s.report_id
    ORDER BY
       to_char(s.last_print, 'DD/MM/YYYY'))

       LOOP

      NULL;
      --use CUR.site HERE FOR YOUR OPERATIONS ...

      END LOOP;
```

Comment: This answer doesn't demonstrate how to do what the OP is trying to do. The bit you commented `-- use CUR.site HERE FOR YOUR OPERATIONS` is the bit the OP is having difficulty with.